# How to ignore part of the functionality in the code if the user types a certain command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The "(Type 1 if you dont want to upload an Image.)" doesn't actually work, how do I make it functional ? For example if someone prefers not to add an image into the embed, they can just type "1" and it will ignore the last question.

```
     if (command === 'call') {
        const questions = [
            { answer: null, field: 'title' },
            { answer: null, field: 'description' },
            { answer: null, field: 'image (**Type 1 if you dont want to upload an Image.**)' },
          ];
          let current = 0;

          const sent = await message.channel.send(
            `**Note 1 of ${questions.length}:**\nWhat would you like the ${questions[current].field} be?`,
          );
      
          const filter = (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id;
          const collector = sent.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
            max: questions.length,
            time: MINUTES * 60 * 1000,
          });
      

          collector.on('collect', (message) => {

            questions[current++].answer = message.content;
            const hasMoreQuestions = current < questions.length;
      
            if (hasMoreQuestions) {
              message.channel.send(
                `**Note ${current + 1} of ${questions.length}:**\nWhat would you like the ${questions[current].field} be?`,
              );
            }
          });

          collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if (reason === 'time') {
              return message.channel.send(
                `${collected.size} questions out of ${questions.length} in ${MINUTES} minutes. Timed out. Please contact Conspet if you think it's a bug. `,
              );
            }
      
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(questions[0].answer)
              .setDescription(questions[1].answer)
              .setColor(0000)
              .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/q99pFdqE5zoDRfQb7DDLVOwEpnN6r4OQRR2ZxvqizpM/%3Fwidth%3D434%26height%3D434/https/media.discordapp.net/attachments/814046875555463169/867305615684010014/ezgif.com-optimize.gif?width=270&height=270")
              .setImage(questions[2].answer)
              .setFooter(`Blue Origin - SFS © 2020.` + ` Announcement Identity: ` + makeid(10))
            client.channels.cache.get('814036808304164895').send(embed)
            client.channels.cache.get('814036808304164895').send("**Ping** - @everyone")
          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it's the last question, you could check the answer. You should only use `.setImage()` if the answer is not `"1"`.

```js
collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'time') {
    return message.channel.send(
      `${collected.size} questions out of ${questions.length} in ${MINUTES} minutes. Timed out. Please contact Conspet if you think it's a bug. `,
    );
  }

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(questions[0].answer)
    .setDescription(questions[1].answer)
    .setColor(0000)
    .setThumbnail('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/q99pFdqE5zoDRfQb7DDLVOwEpnN6r4OQRR2ZxvqizpM/%3Fwidth%3D434%26height%3D434/https/media.discordapp.net/attachments/814046875555463169/867305615684010014/ezgif.com-optimize.gif?width=270&height=270')
    .setFooter(`Blue Origin - SFS © 2020.` + ` Announcement Identity: ` + makeid(10));

  if (questions[2].answer !== '1')
    embed.setImage(questions[2].answer);

  client.channels.cache.get('814036808304164895').send(embed);
  client.channels.cache
    .get('814036808304164895')
    .send('**Ping** - @everyone');
});
```